# Is there a way to listen to multiple python sockets at once

Tags: python, sockets

can i listen to multiple sockets at once

The code i am using to monitor the sockets at the moment is:

```
while True:
    for sock in socks:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
        print "received message:", data
```

but that waits at the line:

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
```

until it recieves a message.

Is there a way to make it listen to multiple sockets at once

EDIT: not sure if it is completely relevant but i am using UDP

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is. You need to use non-blocking calls to receive from the sockets. Check out the [select module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)

If you are reading from the sockets here is how you use it:

```
while True:
    # this will block until at least one socket is ready
    ready_socks,_,_ = select.select(socks, [], []) 
    for sock in ready_socks:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # This is will not block
        print "received message:", data
```

Note: you can also pass an extra argument to `select.select()` which is a timeout. This will keep it from blocking forever if no sockets become ready.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly, [this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-pysocks/section4.html) was also really helpful

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: How is the `socks` defined? would you please complete the example?

Comment: How to know which port it comes from?

Answer (score 3):

A slight update to [entropy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414304/entropy)'s answer for Python 3:
The `selectors` module allows high-level and efficient I/O multiplexing, built upon the select module primitives. Users are encouraged to use this module instead, unless they want precise control over the OS-level primitives used.
As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/selectors.html#module-selectors)