# What is the ideal stack_size for a thread in Python that connects to a socket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a Python script that spawns 300 threads. Each thread connects to a socket on a given port and receives in average around 500 characters until it closes the socket.

I currently have this setup:

```
threading.stack_size(524288)
```

which means 512KB.
I gave it a shot using just 128KB, and it worked fine on a very small set of tests. But I have no idea if what I am doing is right. Ideally, i would like to set the size even lower than 128KB.

So, my question is how much RAM does a kind of socket connection that I have, can use in AVERAGE?
I know its somehow a non-standard question, and I know it varies in alot of ways, but I just want to hear some average numbers.
Would it be okay if I use just 64KB , or less?

Thank you for your time you took to read this and I will appreciate your answers.

Regards.

A good example of a thread could be an attempt to send an email.

Comment: I think this is a "how long is a piece of string?" question. IMO the only realistic way to get good data is to test various stack sizes using your code in your execution environment with realistic load.

Comment: Keep dropping it by powers of two and load testing.  When it fails, double the size.

Comment: @NPE: I know it somehow makes very little sense, but I am hoping someone who faced this at some point in time could give me some average numbers. Like "Yes, I have a similar socket function and it consumes 5KB of memory".

Comment: You many be interested in the Stack Overflow question [Is there a way to listen to multiple python sockets at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101333/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-multiple-python-sockets-at-once).  For yet another approach see the docs for [`asyncore`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html).

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but the correct answer is "don't do that; use Twisted".

Comment: I do not really trust libraries ( I know how that sounds) this is why I love working with low level connections.

Comment: “I do not really trust libraries”? What do you think `threading` is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *stack size* set by `threading.stack_size` is the amount of memory to allocate for the call stack in threads.

This amount must be allocated when the thread is created.  It cannot be changed.

Unsurprisingly (I hope) this value limits the number of frames that can exist on the call stack.  Surprisingly (perhaps) it applies to the C call stack - not the Python call stack.

On CPython, the Python call stack and the C call stack are correlated - though they are separate things.

This means that if the Python code you run in a thread makes enough calls to make the C call stack deep enough that it needs more memory than you've allowed using `threading.stack_size` then your Python process will crash.

Therefore, if you tweak this too low and you'll find your application will become unreliable - with failures presenting as mysterious crashes.

To re-iterate, there are two concepts here.  First, there's the amount of memory that actually gets allocated when you start a thread: that's controlled by `threading.stack_size`.  Second, there's the amount of memory that the thread's call stack actually needs to use.  The former *must* always be at least as large as the later in order for your program to work.  You can control the former using `threading.stack_size` but you can only control the latter by how you write your program.

If you want to conserve memory then consider using non-blocking sockets all in a single thread instead (simply using non-blocking sockets doesn't reduce memory usage - but using one thread instead of 300 threads will certainly reduce memory usage).

Comment: I am already using non-blocking sockets, and the maximum memory usage is exactly what I am trying to reduce. I am concern about the average memory usage PER THREAD, so I can tweak the stack_size I set.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time into this, and I am aware of the related issues beside the stack_size I set. However, that doesnt really answer my question)). Having one thread instead of 300 won't help me at all. I am using Queue threading. Controling the amount of memory that actually gets alocated is exactly what I want to do. I know I cant control what it actually uses besides that. What I would want to know how much in average/ballpark does that kind of socket dialogue consumes. Would 64KB be too low ?

Comment: Sorry.  I think that I answered those questions already - both by pointing out that the average doesn't matter, only the maximum matters, and by explaining that the amount your program will require depends on your program.  Perhaps it would help clarify matters if I explicitly stated that it is not the *socket* that is using stack memory.  The socket is a *heap* allocated object.  You can create a million sockets and not increase your *stack* memory usage at all.  It is your what your program *does* that will determine how much stack memory it needs.

Comment: I finally understand what you intended to say, and now that I think of it you are right. I have to measure them some different way. Thanks for the answer.