# I am creating a Twitch-focused IRC bot in Python, however it is getting the responses slowly. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, sockets, irc, twitch

As the title says, although this is also the first time I have used Python to really do anything big. I'm not all that used to the language yet, so this is probably my missing something. The code is fairly short and is as followed, with username and private pass removed:

```
import re
import socket
import sys
import time
import string

HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667                        
NICK = ""
PASS = ""
CHAN = ""                   

RATE = (20/30) # messages per second
CHAT_MSG=re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")

def chat(sock, msg):
    sock.send("PRIVMSG #{} :{}".format(cfg.CHAN, msg))

public = socket.socket()
public.connect((HOST, PORT))
public.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(PASS).encode("utf-8"))
public.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(NICK).encode("utf-8"))
public.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(CHAN).encode("utf-8"))

private = socket.socket()
private.connect((HOST, PORT))
private.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(PASS).encode("utf-8"))
private.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(NICK).encode("utf-8"))
private.send("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags twitch.tv/commands  {}\r\n".format(CHAN).encode("utf-8"))

while True:
    channelResponse = public.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    privateResponse = private.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    if privateResponse == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        private.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        privateResponseUsername = re.search(r"\w+", privateResponse).group(0) # return the entire match
        privateResponseMessage = CHAT_MSG.sub("", privateResponse)
        print(privateResponseUsername + ": " + privateResponseMessage)

    if channelResponse == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
        public.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
    else:
        username = re.search(r"\w+", channelResponse).group(0) # return the    entire match
        message = CHAT_MSG.sub("", channelResponse)
        print(username + ": " + message)
        time.sleep(1 / RATE)
```

One thing to mention is that I was following a basic template style, however it did not cover implementing whispers into the bot - so I'm having to guess by doing research on how to do that, and it seems to be that the most recommended way is two connections, one for public, one for private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've structured your code, you can't get anything from the `private` socket until you've gotten something from the `public` socket. If IRC didn't send `PING` messages occasionally, this would work even worse.

The way to handle this is to use [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html), and give it your two sockets. Right as soon as one has stuff that can be read, `select` will return, and indicate which socket has bytes available for reading.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101551/32878) has some general code. You might want to modify it to look something like:

```
while True:
    # this will block until at least one socket is ready
    ready_socks,_,_ = select.select([private, public], [], [])
    if private in ready_socks:
        privateResponse += private.recv()
    if public in ready_socks:
        channelResponse += public.recv()

    # check privateResponse buffer, do stuff
    # check channelResponse buffer, do stuff
```

There are a few other things you should keep in mind:

1. The network doesn't have to deliver entire IRC messages at the same time, nor does it have to deliver a single one at a time. You could get "PI", "NG :t", "mi.twitch.tv", "\r\n" as separate messages. So you should accumulate bytes in a buffer, and then when you've got at least one entire message, process it, and remove it from the buffer.
2. UTF-8 characters can span multiple bytes, and might be split up by the network. Don't decode UTF-8 until you're sure you've got an entire message to work with.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten this part set up but I'm not sure how to check the arrays for public/private channel responses in Python - in a while loop. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: arrays? you mean the `privateResponse` and `channelResponse` buffers, which are strings? you've got a lot of options. mostly they revolve around the fact that messages in IRC are conveniently ended by newlines. if there's no newline in the buffer, there are no complete messages. simplest thing is probably to see if there is a newline, and if there is, process everything up to it as a message, and then replace the buffer with everything after the newline.

Comment: That did it. There's an initial pause now, but then both connections behave properly - and get responses immedietly.